# Metaprogramming: How to access parameters of methods inside meta classes

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am learning ruby meta-programming's meta classes concept. i am trying to define method dynamically inside meta-class but the problem which i am facing is i am not able to access "name" inside meta-class.

Below is my code.

```
class Abc

  def add_method(name) 

      class << self  

         define_method "#{name}" do 

         end 

      end 
  end
end

a = Module.const_get("Abc").new
a.add_method("my_method")
a.my_method
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. got solution after some online debugging. Below is the solution

```
class Abc    
  def add_method(name)    
      meta_class = class << self    
        self
      end
      meta_class.class_eval do
         define_method "#{name}" do 

         end    
     end 
  end
end

a = Module.const_get("Abc").new
a.add_method("my_method")
a.my_method
```

Comment: This adds an instance method to your class. I thought you wanted to add a method to `Abc`'s singleton class?